# Write a process's output to a buffer

Tags: c++, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c)

In my c++ program, I'm running an external program using execv/system.

I would like to redirect the output of the program to a buffer in my program,i.e.:

```
char* buff[some size large enough for any possible output];
system(some program);
//THE PROGRAM I JUST RAN IS A SPECIAL BLACK BOX PROGRAM THAT RUNS
//AND PARSE AN HTTP DUMP FILE AND PRINTS IT TO THE SCREEN WHEN RUNNING
//I WANT THE OUTPUT TO GO A BUFFER IN MY PROGRAM.
//THE IDEA IS TO HAVE THE DATA OF THE OUTPUT ON THE BUFFER RATHER THAN ON A FILE

//have the buffer filled with the output of the program
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: search next time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is some other way to do this , but this what comes to my mind

```
char* buff[some size large enough for any possible output];
system(some program >somefile.txt);  

//have the buffer filled with the output of the program
// And redirect it into a file


//Do initial validity checks and open the file



read(somefile.txt,buff,bufflen);
//Read the file

unlink somefile.txt 
//Unlink if the file is not needed
```

Replace bufflen by the number of bytes you want to read from the file.

Comment: Or even just read it on the stream and into a string and then you don't need to worry about sizes (If you are going to write an external file like that)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the output of a sub-process then (in a POSIX/UNIX/Linux world at least) you should really be looking at the use of pipes for inter-process communication. A helpful question/answer on Stackoverflow with links to some good resources is here: [fork(), pipe() and exec() process creation and communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094063/fork-pipe-and-exec-process-creation-and-communication)